# How to avoid code duplication in tree structure with nodes of different type

Tags: c++

I have the following hierarchy (just example):

```
// nodes hierarchy:
// NodeA - NodeB1 - NodeC1 - NodeD1
//                         - NodeD2
//       - NodeB2 - NodeC2
//       - NodeB3 - NodeC3
//                - NodeC4
```

All nodes inherit from the same base class. The hierarchy is fixed, each node has unique functionality that comes from business logic. I would like to obtain children/parent nodes with exact types (i.e. NodeC2* instead of Node* when I have type of its parent: NodeB2* instead of Node*). The working implementation is shown below. The question is **how to avoid large code duplication in implementation of concrete getters**?

```
// Node.h
#include <vector>
struct Node {
    Node* getParent() { return parent; }
    Node* getChild(size_t i) { return children[i]; }
    virtual ~Node() {}

    Node* parent;
    std::vector<Node*> children;
};

// NodeB3.h

// forward declarations
struct NodeA;
struct NodeC3;
struct NodeC4;

struct NodeB3 : public Node {
// awful code duplication inside each NodeX.h
    NodeA* getNodeA();
    NodeC3* getNodeC3();
    NodeC4* getNodeC4();
};

// NodeA.h
class NodeB1;
class NodeB2;
class NodeB3;
struct NodeA  : public Node {
    NodeB1* getNodeB1();
    NodeB2* getNodeB2();
    NodeB3* getNodeB3();
};

// NodeC3.h
class NodeB3;
struct NodeC3 : public Node {
    NodeB3* getNodeB3();
};
// NodeC4.h
class NodeB3;
struct NodeC4 : public Node {
    NodeB3* getNodeB3();
};

// NodeB3.cpp

#include <cassert>

// awful code duplication inside each NodeX.cpp
NodeA* NodeB3::getNodeA() {
    return static_cast<NodeA*>(getParent()); 
}
NodeC3* NodeB3::getNodeC3() {
    return static_cast<NodeC3*>(getChild(0)); 
}
NodeC4* NodeB3::getNodeC4() {
    return static_cast<NodeC4*>(getChild(1)); 
}

// main.cpp
int main() {
    NodeB3* nb3 = new NodeB3();
    nb3->parent = new NodeA();
    nb3->children.push_back(new NodeC3());
    nb3->children.push_back(new NodeC4());

    // desired use
    NodeA* na = nb3->getNodeA();
    NodeC3* nc3 = nb3->getNodeC3();
    NodeC4* nc4 = nb3->getNodeC4();
}
```

Comment: Why not put all common code in the parent class? Or create an intermediate class, inheriting `Node` and that is a parent class for all the other `NodeXY` classes, for the common code?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Because concrete return type is not known. Each class has unique concrete getters for its parent/child, so it is not clear how to put their common implementation in some base class.

Comment: Your comments in the code says "similar to implementation of NodeB3". ***How*** "similar"? *How* is the "concrete type ... not known"?

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `assert` macro is usually disabled for release builds. Besides, apparently crashing when the assertion fails is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Similar, but not the same =). I will add this implementation for clarity. The assert behavior do exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Instead of getNodeA, getNodeC3 etc why not use getNode<T> ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have added 'similar implementations'

Comment: @auburg It is a nice idea, but it is not clear for me how to restrict it to only allowed types. Should I specialize this member function for different template parameters?

Comment: just use `dynamic_cast<T*>` in the templated getter. It will return `nullptr` if the conversion is invalid

Comment: @Useless Types are known at compile time, that is why I would like to use only static_cast in release builds. (dynamic_cast is just for checking correctness in test builds, it has some performance overhead)

Comment: If types were known at compile time, you wouldn't be holding a base class pointer in the first place. You are, which means you've lost/discarded some type information at compile time, and you're trying to recover it at runtime.

Comment: @Useless Sometimes I really need to discard some type information and use `Node::getParent`, `Node::getChild` (as general interface to traverse the tree), but sometimes I have this information (from dynamic dispatch in virtual methods) and would like not to perform dynamic_cast, because I know exact types of children/parent.

Comment: I don't understand why `getParent` exists in the first place, since (a pointer to) any derived type is implicitly convertible to (a pointer to) the base class. I also don't understand why you don't just use `static_cast` directly when you know the dynamic type. And why are you avoiding `dynamic_cast`? For performance? Some other reason?

Comment: [tree234](http://cplusplus.kurttest.com/notes/tree234.html) ?

Comment: @Useless 1. `getParent` exists in the first place, because it is required to traverse the tree when we don't have information about concrete types (suppose we introduce Entity::getName() and print name of each entity) 2. `dynamic_cast` is not required (it is used for early detecting debugging errors), I removed it from example, because, I agree, it is rather misleading. 3. I avoid `dynamic_cast` not only for performance reason. I check concrete getter functions interface once and 100% sure that any use of them is then correct, while  with `getNode<T>` any use is dangerous (T is anything).

Comment: @VictorGubin The question is not about classical data structures, but about class design.

Comment: @Bhavin Chirag Are there any reason to use 4 different node types with inheritance ?

Comment: @VictorGubin Actually in example there are 11 different node types, in real code this number is near 30. Each node type represents some entity in project tree of gui application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a meaningful base class, so don't try and use one.

Write the different traversals you need as visitors.

```
struct NodeB1;
struct NodeB2;
struct NodeB3;  
struct NodeA {
    std::unique_ptr<NodeB1> child1;
    std::unique_ptr<NodeB2> child2;
    std::unique_ptr<NodeB3> child3;

    template<typename UnaryOperation>
    void walk_down_tree(UnaryOperation unary_op)
    {
        unary_op(*this);
        child1->walk_down_tree(unary_op);
        child2->walk_down_tree(unary_op);
        child3->walk_down_tree(unary_op);
    }

    template<typename UnaryOperation>
    void walk_up_tree(UnaryOperation unary_op)
    {
        unary_op(*this);
    }
};

struct NodeC1;
struct NodeB1 {
    NodeA * parent;
    std::unique_ptr<NodeC1> child1;

    template<typename UnaryOperation>
    void walk_down_tree(UnaryOperation unary_op)
    {
        unary_op(*this);
        child1->walk_down_tree(unary_op);
    }

    template<typename UnaryOperation>
    void walk_up_tree(UnaryOperation unary_op)
    {
        unary_op(*this);
        parent->walk_up_tree(unary_op);
    }
};

// ... and so on
```

And have actions like

```
struct PrintName { 
    template<typename Node>
    void operator()(Node & node)
    {
        std::cout << node.name << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Frobnicate {
    Foo results;
    void operator()(NodeA & a)
    {
         results.frobA(a);
    }
    void operator()(NodeB1 & b1)
    {
         results.frobB(b1);
    }
    // more overloads ...
};
```

See also [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) for a similar scheme

Comment: Thanks for answer! `UnaryOperation` seems too restrictive for me. I can't figure out how, for example, implement `virtual std::string Node::getName()` which I would like to print during tree traversal (it is virtual because some of classes have fixed name `return "MyName"`, while other return member string `return this->name`)

Comment: @BhavinChirag I've suggested some types which you'd pass as `UnaryOperation`

Comment: I see. This is really clever approach.